# How do I connect ADLS Gen 2 to an AKS web service securely?

Tags: python, azure-data-lake, azure-aks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a model hosted on AKS that requires reading a file in ADLS Gen 2 for feature engineering in Python. I've provisioned AKS with a managed identity and have granted that identity storage blob data contributor access to ADLS Gen 2.

Given this, how do I connect my AKS web service to ADLS Gen 2 in my Python code? I see documentation to do this given a client secret and client ID [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python), but can I do this with a managed identity without explicitly using a client secret and client ID?

Comment: please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/9498#issuecomment-575360112

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Not yet, but my plan is to try something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-azure-ad-identity. I think things are a bit more involved since I need to assign an AAD pod identity.

Comment: So there is no way that you can just permanently attach adlsgen2  to kubernetes as a volume then refer to that volume in your python code? (i.e. like DataBricks)

Answer (score 0):

To use the managed identity to access ADLS Gen 2, you just need to use [`ManagedIdentityCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.managedidentitycredential?view=azure-python) instead of [`ClientSecretCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-python) of the [code sample you provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python#connect-by-using-azure-active-directory-ad).

```
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format("https", storage_account_name), credential=credential)
```

**Note**: The code above just applies to the system-assigned managed identity, if you are using the user-assigned managed identity, you need to use `client_id` parameter.

```
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(client_id = "<client-id of your user-assigned managed identity>")
```